How to Trigger Alerts Based on 15-Minute Bar Close While Using a 30-Minute Chart in Pine Script?
I'm working on a Pine Script indicator in TradingView that needs to trigger alerts based on the close of 15-minute bars, even though my chart is set to a 30-minute timeframe. I'm encountering issues with the alert configuration. i set an alert for once-per-bar but it triggers as soon as i create the alert. Here is the relevant part of my Pine Script code:

// Define the timeframe to monitor (15-minute in this case)
timeframe_to_check = "15"

// Get the close price from the 15-minute timeframe
close_15m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe_to_check, close)

// Reset stop_triggered at the start of a new 15-minute bar
var bool stop_triggered = false

if (close_15m < sl_price) and open_position
    stop_triggered := true
else
    stop_triggered := false

// Alert condition for stop-loss hit
alert_if_price_hit_stop = stop_triggered and open_position

alertcondition(alert_if_price_hit_stop, title="Stop Loss Hit", message="The stop loss level has been hit in {{ticker}}")

I tried setting up the alert in TradingView with the "Once per bar close" option, but it triggers based on the 30-minute bar close, not the 15-minute bar close as intended. I also considered using "Once per minute," but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to ensure accurate 15-minute bar close detection while avoiding unnecessary alerts.
I expected the alert to trigger based on the close of the 15-minute bars, even though my chart is set to a 30-minute timeframe. The goal is to accurately detect and respond to the 15-minute bar closes within the higher timeframe chart.

If you are requesting data from lower timeframes, then you should ideally use  request.security_lower_tf() function.

Requests data from a specified symbol from a lower timeframe than the
chart's. The function returns an array containing one element for each
closed lower timeframe intrabar inside the current chart's bar.

If you use request.security() on lower timeframes, the behavior might not be what you expect. It is explained here.

When calling this function to access a lower timeframe, it will
evaluate the expression from the LTF context. However, it can only
return the results from a single intrabar (LTF bar) on each chart bar.
The intrabar that the function returns data from on each historical
chart bar depends on the lookahead value in the function call. When
using barmerge.lookahead_on, it will return the first available
intrabar from the chart period. When using barmerge.lookahead_off, it
will return the last intrabar from the chart period. On realtime bars,
it returns the last available value of the expression from the
timeframe, regardless of the lookahead value, as the realtime intrabar
information retrieved by the function is not yet sorted.

Alternatively, you can just set your chart to 15min timeframe and request data from 30min timeframe. That's what I would probably do.
